# Looking for OnLog Event - log4net

Tags: c#, log4net

I am using Log4net to produce different kind of logs and using RollingFileAppenders which rolls on a given size.

Now i have a new requirement that a log should be visible on a windows form therefore i am looking for some event that can be handled on each log entry within my application so i can display that particular log entry in my form as well.

Or there may be some appender which gives such functionality.

Any idea on this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd suggest writing your own appender - it's really easy to do:

1. Create a class that inherits from AppenderSkeleton
2. Override the Append method

Simple!

[Here](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#U2NdYsurJZ4/Platform/Tags/SafetyStockCalc/2.0.1708.1/Source/Lokad.SafetyStock.Windows/TextBoxAppender.cs&q=AppenderSkeleton%20append%20lang:c%23&sa=N&cd=4&ct=rc) is an example of a custom appender that updates a textbox.

Comment: I just added an example for you. You can locate others on http://www.google.com/codesearch if you need them

Answer (score -1):

As I suggest in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2452562/when-does-log4net-write-or-commit-the-log-to-file/2452978#2452978), you could set up a [MemoryAppender](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.Appender.MemoryAppender.html) and monitor log messages in memory. It does not expose an event but you could easily set up a timer that [retrieves the latest messages](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.Appender.MemoryAppender.GetEvents.html).

Comment: Oh-key, a bit of constructive criticism with the downvote is always appreciated. If not, why downvote?

Comment: Author of the question can't take the responsibility of this deed :) Voter must added a comment.

Comment: @Mubashar Ahmad - no problem, glad you got a solution :)