# log4net is not working while using parallel loops

Tags: c#, log4net, parallel.foreach

I am using basic Parallel.Foreach loop on Random numbers to log number itself using log4net.

Here is my code to log 5000 messages on parallel threads

```
            Logger logger = new Logger();
            var numbers = Enumerable.Range(1, 5000);
            ParallelOptions parallelOptions =
                   new ParallelOptions()
                   {
                       MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Environment.ProcessorCount
                   };
            Parallel.ForEach(numbers, parallelOptions, number =>
            {
                logger.Write(Level.Info, "main method", "" + number + "", loggingParameters);
            });
```

But in the end only see 1600 messages in the log file.

Is this a known issue with log4net ? or am i doing something wrong here ?

Comment: What are you trying to do this in parallel?  Parallel activities only benefit independent CPU-intensive tasks, not I/O.

Comment: You might have to the explicitly flush the log before exiting the application, so that log4net can write everything thats queued up.

Comment: @DStanley It's just a sample. I am trying to integrated log4net in my application where we have several parallel activities

Comment: @jrummell I will try that thanks

Comment: Please keep it to [one question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36161947/log4net-asynchronous-logging-is-not-working-with-parallel-threads) and update that one if you have additional information.

Comment: @jrummell Could you please look a this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36161947/log4net-logging-is-not-working-with-parallel-threads. I tried that seting in web config but its not working

Comment: @CodeCaster Yeah i updated that question. Will close this soon Thanks